# Web Scraping with bash

Tags: arrays, bash, url, web-scraping, scripting

I am doing web scraping with bash. I have these URL which is saved in a file URL.txt

```
?daypartId=1&amp;catId=1
?daypartId=1&amp;catId=11
?daypartId=1&amp;catId=2
```

I want to pass these URL to an array in another file which would append in the base URL **https://www.mcdelivery.com.pk/pk/browse/menu.html**
I want to append all the URl in URL.txt file in the end of the base url one by one.

Comment: Show us what you tried so far

Comment: you may want  to look into using python for this

Comment: while IFS= read -r line ;do
        echo $line
done < "${text1.txt}"


# while [ $text1.txt -lt 2 ]
# do
curl https://www.mcdelivery.com.pk/pk/browse/menu.html${line} | grep -o '<span class="starting-price">.*</span>' | sed 's/<[^>]\+>//g' >> 123.txt

Comment: I want a loop that can iterate over the url one by one and fetch the data through curl.

Comment: you shouldn't open duplicate questions https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62235280/get-data-from-one-file-to-another-bash-web-scraping

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get data from one file to another (Bash) - Web Scraping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62235280/get-data-from-one-file-to-another-bash-web-scraping)

Comment: No, I want to loop over the URL and append it to the base URL. I just want a loop to iterate over the urls and append them in the base URL

Comment: `ARRAY=() while read -r LINE do     ARRAY+=("$LINE") done < URL.txt  for LINE in "${ARRAY[@]}" do         echo $LINE     curl https://www.mcdelivery.com.pk/pk/browse/menu.html$LINE | grep -o '<h5 class="product-title">.*</h5>' | sed 's/<[^>]\+>//g' >> price.txt  done`                               I have come up with this code but the output repeats itself like it only gives the output of the main page can you please spot the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need a way to read each line,

```
while IFS= read -r line ;do
        echo $line
done < "${file}"
```

Then inside of that file reading loop you will need to perform the operation to append and use the $line you have gotten .

```
curl http://example.com${line}
```

Comment: while IFS= read -r line ;do
        echo $line
done < "${text1.txt}"
while [ $text1.txt -lt 2 ]
do
curl https://www.mcdelivery.com.pk/pk/browse/menu.html${line} | grep -o '<span class="starting-price">.*</span>' | sed 's/<[^>]\+>//g' >> 123.txt

Comment: I am trying to do this. I am new to bash. Can you help me with the array to loop over the iteration so that we can append them infront of the url. Thanks

Comment: I am trying to loop over the content that are in text1.txt.

Comment: `ARRAY=() while read -r LINE do     ARRAY+=("$LINE") done < URL.txt  for LINE in "${ARRAY[@]}" do         echo $LINE     curl https://www.mcdelivery.com.pk/pk/browse/menu.html$LINE | grep -o '<h5 class="product-title">.*</h5>' | sed 's/<[^>]\+>//g' >> price.txt  done`         I have come up with this code but the output repeats itself like it only gives the output of the main page can you please spot the error?

Comment: try it like this and just print out the output to the screen and see what is going on, I think there may be an issue with your sed or grep but haven't checked..   typeset url="https://www.mcdelivery.com.pk/pk/browse/menu.html"
while IFS= read -r line ;do
  curl "${url}${line}" | grep -o '<h5 class="product-title">.*</h5>' | sed 's/<[^>]\+>//g'
done < "URL.txt"